# How to move numbers down and combine them if they are the same in a list of lists (python)

Tags: python, list

I have a list that has 4 other lists inside and the lists inside the list have 4 0
Some of the random zeros are 1 i need to move them to the very bottom of the list (the last list inside the main list)
and if there are two 1 on top of each other turn them in to a 2 and move it to the bottom

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]

for col in range(len(board[0])):
            for row in range(len(board)-1, -1, -1):
                if board[row][col] != 0:
                    for r in range(row+1, len(board)):
                        if board[r][col] == 0:
                            board[r][col] = board[r-1][col]
                            board[r-1][col] = 0
```

I have the following python code with a board and a for loop that only moves everything down
what do i need to add so the 1 add up

I need the output to be

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this directly in numpy which uses rows and cols directly:

```
import numpy as np

board = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]

nb = np.array(board)
nb[3] = nb[:3,:].sum(axis = 0)  #calculate sum of top 3 rows for each column
nb[:3,:] = 0   # set top 3 rows to 0 in each column
print(nb.tolist())
```

which gives:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the core tenets of python is writing very readable code. I often find it helpful to simplify problems like this by first defining some useful variables before running any logic which will help make your code (and thinking) a little clearer.

First we'll define the bounds of what we want to loop over and then the row index of our target (bottom) row.

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]

n_cols = len(board[0])

# don't iterate over the last row since that's our target row
n_rows = len(board) - 1

final_row_index = n_rows # = len(board) - 1
```

Now we can iterate over the columns: `n_cols` and the rows: `n_rows` and add the elements to `board[final_row_index][col]`

```
for col in range(n_cols):
    for row in range(n_rows):
        
        board[final_row_index][col] += board[row][col]
        # a += b is equivalent to a = a + b
        # we don't need to check to see if the cell is equal to zero since adding zero will not change our answer

        # now zero out the cell (since we're "moving" the ones to the bottom)
        board[row][col] = 0
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Just count them and recreate the board:

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [sum(board[i][j] for i in range(4)) for j in range(4)]]
```